# can not hear playback sounds ( asterisk )

Tags: asterisk

I'm running asterisk 14.2.1 on ubuntu 16.04 in a VirtualBox with 1g ram, 1.7 ghz and bridged adapter for networking.
when I use a softphone installed the host machine to call an extension which playback a gsm sound file everything works and I see an msg indication that the sound is playing but I don't hear it on the phone (it work once from time to time).
if you may help thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide quite enough info - what do you mean you see a 'msg indication' that a sound is playing?  Can you play other sounds (eg: speaker-test) succesfully and hear the audio?

If no this is an audio in VM question.  If yes, then this is likely softphone related.  If the user agent (softphone) is on the PBX then likely not a connectivity issue.  Have you disabled the firewall on the PBX for testing?

Comment: I meant a msg in the asterisk CLI ...anyway I appreciate your help but it was a problem in the softphone after all :)